# How Can I Subscribe To Firebase data using AngularFire2 on initial route load?

Tags: angular, angularfire2, angular2-router

I'm using angular-cli to build an angularfire2 application.

I'm having an issue where upon initial child sub route load, angularfire2 throws an error in the console:

error_handler.js:47 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

This happens when my page "refreshes". If I navigate away from the component and back to it after a refresh, the data loads just fine and I don't receive the error. I'm not sure if this is a bug with Angular2, AngularFire2, or if I'm doing something wrong. Has anyone had this problem? Here is my relevant component code:

```js
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild, OnDestroy}from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable, AngularFireModule} from 'angularfire2';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: 'users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['users.component.scss', '../shared/styles/dashboard.scss']
})
export class EmployeesComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private groupKey: string;
  private groupAdmin: string;
  private user: any;
  private _auth: any;

  private positions: FirebaseListObservable < any > ;
  private users: FirebaseListObservable < any > ;

  constructor(private af: AngularFire, private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.af.auth.subscribe(auth => {
      this._auth = auth;
      let currentUser = this.af.database.object('/Users/' + this._auth.uid).take(1).subscribe(user => {
        this.groupKey = user.group;
        this.users = this.af.database.list('/Users', {
          query: {
            orderByChild: 'group',
            equalTo: this.groupKey
          }
        });
        this.positions = this.af.database.list('/Groups/' + this.groupKey + '/Positions');
        this.af.database.object('/Groups/' + this.groupKey + '/admin').take(1).subscribe(group => {
          this.groupAdmin = group.admin;
        });
      });
    });
  }



  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.users.subscribe().unsubscribe();
    this.positions.subscribe().unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must refactory your `ngOnDestroy` method, because it is wrong, first if you are using `async` pipe inside your template you don't need to unsubscribe and if you don't, inside your `ngOnInit` you should save a reference to `unsubscribe` function for each `subscription` call and then call them on `ngOnDestroy`([you can read more about it here)](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3030-canceling-rxjs-observables-with-ngondestroy-in-angular-2-beta-6.htm).

Comment: I just removed my ngOnDestroy method sense it isn't needed. I'm seeing weird behavior where it now re-routes to the parent component on a refresh.

Comment: Disregard the last comment, that is because of my own stupid code.

Comment: This fixed my issue. Thank you very much. Also, thanks for pointing me to that article. That makes complete sense.